# Unless I put index.php, I am not recieving the $_GET['url']

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

I have a vhost called quick-mvc and I have a .htaccess file in the root dir.
I have mod_rewrite.so activated. I know that mod_rewrite is not recommended but it is what I am using now and would like to get this working. Thank you!

**.htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %[REQUEST_FILENAME] !-d
RewriteCond %[REQUEST_FILENAME] !-f
RewriteCond %[REQUEST_FILENAME] !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

**in the browser ex 1**

```
http://quick-mvc/one/two/three/test
```

$_GET['url'] returns "index.php"

**in the browser ex 2**

```
http://quick-mvc/index.php/one/two/three/test
```

$_GET['url'] returns "index.php/one/two/three/test"

**What I would like to accompish**
I would like to return what ex 2 shows even whether I add index.php like ex 1. I would also like index.php not to show up. Though I can code this out easily with php.

Comment: You should take a look at the documentation of the rewriting module. Especially the variables like `REQUEST_URI` are of interest for you, they allow easier access to the actual request you are interested in: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Another thing: I see no reason why the rewriting module should be 2not recommended"... What indeed is true is that using `.htaccess` style files should be avoided if possible, since those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and _really_ slow the server down. So if you have access to the host configuration you should place your rewriting rules there instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example reminds me of how Drupal used to approach url rewriting to their front controller.  Checking Drupal 7, they have changed the way they do this.

Drupal 7 .htaccess (stripped down):

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

You could take a similar approach, and then in index.php:

```
<?php 
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$parts = parse_url($url);
```

The php function parse_url should give you the path and query string.

```
$your_url = $parts['path'];
```

If placed in the web root, and we visit this url:

```
http://example.com/foo/bar/baz?bat=qux
```

parse_url gives:

```
array
  'path' => string '/foo/bar/baz'
  'query' => string 'bat=qux'
```

Peek at some of the other frameworks to see how they do it.

Comment: Thank you. This might be what arkascha was talking about with REQUEST_URI. I see this working pretty well actually. The question still stands on using index.php or not. I can trim index.php out, but is this necessary?

Comment: You don't need to care or trim out the index.php of the path if your canonical urls do not include it. i.e. urls look like `http://example.com/foo/bar` not `http://example.com/index.php/foo/bar`